# dynamically set Setter in java

Tags: java

well this is my code
i am getting the attr in String (attr is column name) now i want to set it to the object which i made in MedicineParam for example if attr contains dosage then the setter should also be set itself so dosage also i cant use

```
if(rs.getString("dosage") != null)
medici.setDosage(rs.getString("dosage"));
```

because if a field is not there then it will throw a sql exception

```
public ArrayList<MedicineParam> viewParticularDataOnClick(String medName,
            String attr) {

         ArrayList<MedicineParam> newList = new ArrayList<MedicineParam>();
          try{
         Class.forName(DRIVER);

            String selectTableSQL = "SELECT "+attr+", companyname FROM 
            medicineinfo WHERE companyname != 'doecompany' AND medicinename = '"+medName+"'";
            System.out.println(selectTableSQL);
            Statement statement = this.checkconnection().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
            final String s = "medici.set"+attr;
            while (rs.next()) {
                MedicineParam medici =new MedicineParam();
                if(rs.getString("companyname") != null)
                medici.setCompanyname(rs.getString("companyname"));
                if(rs.getString(attr) != null)

                medici.set...??.....(rs.getString(attr)); // THIS LINE how to set the setter w r t the name of attr 
                newList.add(medici);
             }
            rs.close();
            statement.close();
            this.checkconnection().close();
          }
         catch(Exception e){
         }

           return newList;  
    }
```

......

```
public class MedicineParam {

private long id;

private String companyname;
private String medicineName;
private String description;
private String dosage;
private String sideEffects;
private String warnings;
private String overdose;
private String interaction;
private String url;
//setter 
//getter...

}
```

Any help?

Comment: You could use reflection or a map of attribute names to attribute getter functions. Or better yet, redesign your code because this doesn't sound like a good design.

Comment: What does your `medicineinfo` table actually look like? It's really uncommon to get the column name dynamically from user input, so there is probably a better way to do this if you explain the problem a bit more. Where do the `attr` values come from etc?

Comment: @MickMnemonic column name of the table is exactly like the objects in MedicineParam  `if(rs.getString("companyname") != null)
                medici.setCompanyname(rs.getString("companyname"));
                if(rs.getString(attr) != null)

                medici.set...??..(rs.getString(attr));` in this line companyname is table column and setCompanyname setting the value,, this line is ok but when i am dynamically sending the parameter name of column in attr variable.i must also set the MedicineParam  setter accordingly and attr coming from top of the code its a variable of this method

Comment: So you can't just show all the 9 columns of a given medicine at the same time (in a grid or similar)? That would make the UI/UX much simpler, and you could fetch much more data with a single query. To me, it seems that your UI is unintuitive, and that's making the data access unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @MickMnemonic no i cant show all 9 column becuase it is making the UI/UX huge i mean HUGE because all column have HUGE data in it... but this is not the problem.. the problem is in the question

Comment: OK, one more question: if `MedicineParam` will only ever have two of its fields filled (`companyname`) and the one corresponding to `attr`, what do you need that class for? You could just return a `Map<String, String>` from that method, sort of like what tima's answer suggests. Finally, you _need_ to use `PreparedStatement`s for the query; otherwise it's open to SQL injection and you'll see problems with medicine names that contain single quotes.

Comment: this is not only method in the web scrapper tool that i am making.. that class is already being used in different methods... for this method tima's answer is respectable. and for sql injection this is for localhost and wont be live because i am collecting data only :) thanks . Tima thanks :) you made my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't create the getters and setters for some columns, you can add these columns into a specific or generic Map in the MedicineParam object.

MedicineParam additions:

```
private Map<String, String> attributes;

public void addAttribute(String attribute, String value) {
    if (this.attributes == null) {
        this.attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    this.attributes.put(attribute, value);
}

public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
}

public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
}
```

In your while loop, use this:

```
if(rs.getString(attr) != null) {
    medici.addAttribute(attr, rs.getString(attr));
}
```

You can change the Map to be a `Map<String, Object>` to have a more generic map if you need to.

You can then get the values from the object:

```
medici.getAttributes().get("key");
```